# Insert Info Table (column_Name) Select column_name from Table2 #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 2

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Okay so this question has been asked to death on here but I still haven't found the actual MySql statement answer. Just a lot of reasons why it doesn't work. For someone that is new to SQL that doesn't really help me, I need an example. This is what I have:

```
**Table One**

    key             bigint(4)               UNSIGNED                     auto_increment                         
    username        varchar(10)             utf8_general_ci                                          
    score           bigint(5)               UNSIGNED                                                
    password        varchar(60)             utf8_general_ci              NULL   

PRIMARY      PRIMARY 15      key
username     UNIQUE  15      username



**Table Two**
key             bigint(4)                               No      auto_increment                          
username        varchar(10)     utf8_general_ci         No                                   
score_old       bigint(11)                              No                                  
score_high      bigint(11)                              No  .

PRIMARY          PRIMARY    16   key
username         UNIQUE     16   username
```

Both tables have data in them. I want to populate Table Two score_high with Table One score column.
When I try

```
INSERT INTO Table2( score_high ) 
SELECT score
FROM Table1
```

I get

**> > MySQL said:**

> **> #1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 2**

A clear, layman, explanation would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Please don't tag MySQL questions with [tag:sql-server].

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your question. Sorry I can't help; I can only spell MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE Smuckers_Users SET score_high = (SELECT score FROM Smuckers_Info WHERE Smuckers_Users.username = Smuckers_Info.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with

```
INSERT INTO Table2( score_high ) 
SELECT score
FROM Table1
```

You are inserting score from Table1 into Table2, populating only the score_high column

## Question : What unique column is getting in the way ?

Look at the definition of table2. It has two UNIQUE KEYs

- PRIMARY KEY
- username

Since the PRIMARY KEY is an auto_increment column, that is ruled out.

How is UNIQUE KEY on username getting in the way ?

When you insert just a score (say 100,000) into the score_high column, what will the value of username? Most likely a blank field. One row can get in with NULL username. What happens when you attempt to insert another row when you place another score into table? Another row with a blank username. Two rows with blank usernames cannot coexist in table2.

Looking back at what MySQL said

> 1062 - Duplicate entry '' for key 2

Key 2 is the UNIQUE KEY on username

The entry is '' (an empty string)

Mystery solved ( [Q.E.D.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.) )

## Question : How can you populate `table2` ?

```
INSERT INTO Table2( username,score_high ) 
SELECT username,score
FROM Table1
```

This should work just fine because username is unique in table1. Rows from table1 should go into table2 without any incidents.